# NEO4J: Parent Child type filtering where they Share the same Label

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to work out how to return a result set that contains:

- Parent/Child type nodes, with the children having the same label as the parent and thus being a valid item in the main results
- But the Child node should be excluded from the main results if they are included as a "child" match
- Parent should be excluded from the main results if it doesn't contain a Child

I can get this to mostly work but am unable to get the third point working satisfactorily.

My query looks something like the following (unrelated filtering has been removed):

```
MATCH (f:Fruit),(tof:TypeOfFruit)
WITH f, tof
MATCH (f)-[:IS_BANANA|IS_APPLE]->(tof)
WHERE NOT (tof)<-[:IS_APPLE]-(f)<-[:IN_FRUIT_SALAD]-()
OPTIONAL MATCH (tof)<-[:IS_BANANA]-(f)-[r:IN_FRUIT_SALAD]->(f1:Fruit)-[:IS_APPLE]->(tof)
WITH DISTINCT f, COLLECT(DISTINCT f1) AS f1
RETURN { fruit : f, fruitSaladComponents : f1 }
```

So I want to return:

- Bananas that are part of a fruit salad involving Apples
- Apples that are not part of a fruit salad involving Bananas
- The "children" Apples that make up the fruit salad with Bananas

But this query returns Bananas that aren't part of a fruit salad with Apples due to the optional match.

I think there is possibly a way to do this involving Collection `FILTER`ing, but I haven't been able to make it work.

I've tried doing this as a `UNION` (and using `MATCH` instead of `OPTIONAL MATCH`), which gives me probably the closest result to what I'm after, but as each query in the `UNION` is atomic, I end up having to repeat logic from the other query and I figure there must be a way to do this without a `UNION`.

I'm really interested in a Cypher solution rather than a modelling solution, but happy to hear any thoughts.

Link to NEO4J Console: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=x03foa

In there you'll see the `UNION` query which returns the results I'm after, but if possible I don't want to use a `UNION` as there will be conditions where I need to filter based on the results of the first part of the `UNION` plus I don't want to have to add a new `UNION` every-time I add a new fruit and Bananas won't always be the "parent"...etc, etc -

```
MATCH (f:Fruit),(tof:TypeOfFruit)
WITH f, tof
MATCH (tof)<-[:IS_BANANA]-(f)-[:IN_FRUIT_SALAD]->(f1:Fruit)-[:IS_APPLE]->(tof)
WITH DISTINCT f, COLLECT(DISTINCT f1) AS f1
RETURN { fruit : f, fruitSaladComponents : f1 }
UNION
MATCH (f:Fruit),(tof:TypeOfFruit)
WITH f, tof
MATCH (f)-[:IS_APPLE]->(tof)
WHERE NOT (f)<-[:IN_FRUIT_SALAD]-()
WITH DISTINCT f,[] AS f1
RETURN { fruit : f, fruitSaladComponents : f1 }
```

UPDATE 26/05/2015:

The following query works, but is there a better way of doing this - i.e. without the duplication in the `WHERE` and subsequent `OPTIONAL MATCH`?

```
MATCH (f:Fruit),(tof:TypeOfFruit)
WITH f, tof
MATCH (f)-[:IS_BANANA|IS_APPLE]->(tof)
WHERE ((tof)<-[:IS_BANANA]-(f)-[:IN_FRUIT_SALAD]->(:Fruit)-[:IS_APPLE]->(tof)) OR ((tof)<-[:IS_APPLE]-(f) AND NOT (f)<-[:IN_FRUIT_SALAD]-())
OPTIONAL MATCH (tof)<-[:IS_BANANA]-(f)-[r:IN_FRUIT_SALAD]->(f1:Fruit)-[:IS_APPLE]->(tof)
WITH DISTINCT f, COLLECT(DISTINCT f1) AS f1
RETURN { fruit : f, fruitSaladComponents : f1 }
```

Comment: Plz share a sample graph via http://console.neo4j.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is as above (with a slight variation to move the WHERE clause) -

```
MATCH (f:Fruit),(tof:TypeOfFruit)
WITH f, tof
MATCH (f)-[:IS_BANANA|IS_APPLE]->(tof)
OPTIONAL MATCH (tof)<-[:IS_BANANA]-(f)-[r:IN_FRUIT_SALAD]->(f1:Fruit)-[:IS_APPLE]->(tof)
WITH DISTINCT f, tof, COLLECT(DISTINCT f1) AS f1
WHERE ((tof)<-[:IS_BANANA]-(f)-[:IN_FRUIT_SALAD]->(:Fruit)-[:IS_APPLE]->(tof)) OR ((tof)<-[:IS_APPLE]-(f) AND NOT (f)<-[:IN_FRUIT_SALAD]-())
RETURN { fruit : f, fruitSaladComponents : f1 }
```

If anyone knows of a better solution please advise.